# Unable to access website or SSH or FTP - Google Cloud and wordpress

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform

I have a WordPress site hosted on Google Cloud, and was working very well.
With no apparent motive, stoped working and I can't access to it, neither the front panel or admin panel.

I can't access via FTP o SSH console.

The VM on Google cloud still running as far as I can see.

Errors I get:

When trying to access de website on Google Chrome:

> ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

When trying to access FTP via FileZilla:

> - Error: Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
> - Error: Could not connect to server

When trying to access SSH:

> Connection via Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy Failed Code: 4003 Reason:
> failed to connect to backend You may be able to connect without using
> the Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy.

Comment: Did the Compute Engine VM's IP address change? Are you using reserved static IP addresses or ephemeral?

Comment: It looks like the instance might have frozen, or the network could have gone down. I would advise you to check the serial logs for any errors and interacting with the instance from the serial console to see if it's still responsive; let us know your findings.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/viewing-serial-port-output
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console

Answer (score 1):

i just want to update this issue.
The problem was that the memory quota.
I've increased the amounth of memory, restarted de VM and all went back to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[This page](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh) with SSH troubleshooting steps might be able to help you.

The issue could be solved by trying these troubleshooting steps. I think it is likely that the first one might be the cause of your issue since you mentioned it did work before.

- Does the instance have a full disk? [Try to expand it](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk)!
- Is the firewall correctly setup, check your firewall rules and ensure that the default-allow-ssh rule is present.
- Check your IAM permissions, do you have the roles required to connect to the VM?
- Enable the serial console from your instance settings, connect and review the logs, they might give you some useful insights.